# Removing contribute rights for user on page breaks jquery

Tags: jquery, access-rights

I have a problem with a Sharepoint aspx page - I need to remove the Contribbute rights for it (so that the users don't see the ribbon anymore) but when I do this, the following script from its masterpage is no longer recognized:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

So this script is set in the masterpage, and seems to only work properly if the user has Contribute rights.

Is it possible that I remove Contribute rights, but also keep the jquery functionality? Most of the page logic requires jquery to work properly.

Thanks,

Comment: where are you removing their permissions? On the page, the library, the site?

Comment: I am removing the permissions from Site Settings- Site Permissions, for a specific group. and this user is in that specific group.

Comment: Does the user have read permissions elsewhere?

Comment: Let me add to David's question: does the user have Read (visitor) permission to /SiteAssets/? He needs to in order to loads those files.